# Cannot boot into Kubuntu 20.04 LTS: CPU pipe A FIF underrun

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, kubuntu, lenovo

**Problem**:
I'm attempting to boot into a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
I get past the Grub menu screen, but I get stuck at a black screen with only one log which is this error: `[drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun`.

**I've tried:**
I've tried disabling Intel C-State as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588457/drmintel-cpu-fifo-underrun-irq-handler-i915-error-cpu-pipe-a-fifo-underru. Which involves editing the Grub config under `/etc/default/grub` and adding the `intel_idle.max_cstate=0` option to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable.

I have also tried this: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/XPS-13-7390-Ubuntu-Screen-flickering/td-p/7430121/page/3. Which involves disabling i915 PSR by adding `i915.enable_psr=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable (since I've seen that this has worked for some people, which I still don't understand what it does).

But no dice.

**Has anyone encountered this and would know how to fix this?**

I've been able to make modifications to my Grub config and lookup my system specs by using a live USB.

**System configuration**:

```
$ inxi -b
System:
 Host: kubuntu Kernel: 5.11.0-27-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5  
 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)  
Machine:
 Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20TK001FUS v: ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen 3  
 serial: <superuser/root required>  
 Mobo: LENOVO model: 20TK001FUS v: SDK0R32862 WIN serial: <superuser/root required>  
 UEFI: LENOVO v: N2VET33W (1.18 ) date: 08/11/2021  
Battery:
 ID-1: BAT0 charge: 80.3 Wh condition: 80.3/80.4 Wh (100%)  
CPU:
 6-Core: Intel Core i7-10750H type: MT MCP speed: 1000 MHz min/max: 800/5000 MHz  
Graphics:
 Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel  
 Device-2: NVIDIA driver: nouveau v: kernel  
 Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa  
 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz  
 OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3  
Network:
 Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi  
Drives:
 Local Storage: total: 484.44 GiB used: 3.24 GiB (0.7%)  
Info:
 Processes: 281 Uptime: 13m Memory: 15.30 GiB used: 680.1 MiB (4.3%) Shell: bash  
 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I found a potential fix. I'm not entirely sure if it fixes my initial issue. But here are the steps I took:

1. Cleaned the partition
2. Re-installed Kubuntu/Ubuntu
3. Booted into safe graphics mode
4. Installed nvidia-driver-470: `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470`

To date, I've been able to restart, and boot successfully into Kubuntu.

Comment: So if driver 470 fixed the problem, what driver was in use before 470 was installed?

Comment: There wasn't any driver installed for my Nvidia card previously. At least that I was aware of.